# Working with variable sized lists with Cython

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, cython, cythonize

I want to cythonise the [python implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#Python) of the [Sutherland-Hogman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm). This algorithm updates a list of vertices according to pretty simple rules (being inside or outside an edge, etc.) but the details are not important. Here is the python version it accepts lists of vertices of polygons oriented clockwise. For instance those:

```
sP=[(50, 150),  (200, 50),  (350, 150), (350, 300), (250, 300), (200, 250), (150, 350),(100, 250), (100, 200)]
cP=[(100, 100), (300, 100), (300, 300), (100, 300)]
```

and calculate their intersection:

```
inter=clip(sP, cP)
```

Here is the code found on rosettacode and slightly modified to return an empty list if there is no intersection.

```
def clip(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):
   def inside(p):
      return(cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])

   def computeIntersection():
      dc = [ cp1[0] - cp2[0], cp1[1] - cp2[1] ]
      dp = [ s[0] - e[0], s[1] - e[1] ]
      n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
      n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
      n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
      return [(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3]

   outputList = subjectPolygon
   cp1 = clipPolygon[-1]

   for clipVertex in clipPolygon:
      cp2 = clipVertex
      inputList = outputList
      outputList = []
      s = inputList[-1]

      for subjectVertex in inputList:
         e = subjectVertex
         if inside(e):
            if not inside(s):
               outputList.append(computeIntersection())
            outputList.append(e)
         elif inside(s):
            outputList.append(computeIntersection())
         s = e
      if len(outputList)<1:
          return []
      cp1 = cp2
   return(outputList)
```

This function is excruciatingly slow for my applications so I tried to cythonize it using numpy. Here is my cython version. I had to define the two functions outside clip because I had error messages about buffer inputs.

cython1

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def clip(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] subjectPolygon,np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] clipPolygon):


    outputList = list(subjectPolygon)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1 = clipPolygon[-1,:]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2 

    for i in xrange(clipPolygon.shape[0]):
       cp2 = clipPolygon[i]
       inputList = outputList
       outputList = []
       s = inputList[-1]

       for subjectVertex in inputList:
          e = subjectVertex
          if inside(e, cp1, cp2):
             if not inside(s, cp1, cp2):
                outputList.append(computeIntersection(cp1, cp2, e, s))
             outputList.append(e)
          elif inside(s, cp1, cp2):
             outputList.append(computeIntersection(cp1, cp2, e, s))
          s = e
       if len(outputList)<1:
         return []
       cp1 = cp2

    return(outputList)


def computeIntersection(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] e, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] s):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dc = cp1-cp2
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dp = s-e
    cdef np.float32_t n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
    cdef np.float32_t n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
    cdef np.float32_t n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] res=np.array([(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3], dtype=np.float32)
    return res

def inside(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] p, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2):
    cdef bint b=(cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])
    return b
```

When I time the two versions I gained only a factor of two in speed-up I need at least 10 times that (or 100x !). Is there something to do ?
How does one deal with list with Cython ?

**EDIT 1:** I followed @DavidW's advice I allocate numpy arrays and trim them instead of using list and I am now using cdef functions, which are supposed to bring 10 times speed up, unfortunately I am seeing no speed-up at all !

cython2

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def clip(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] subjectPolygon,np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] clipPolygon):
    return clip_in_c(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] clip_in_c(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] subjectPolygon,np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] clipPolygon):





    cdef int cp_size=clipPolygon.shape[0]
    cdef int outputList_effective_size=subjectPolygon.shape[0]
    cdef int inputList_effective_size=outputList_effective_size
    #We allocate a fixed size array of size 
    cdef int max_size_inter=outputList_effective_size*cp_size
    cdef int k=-1

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] outputList=np.empty((max_size_inter,2), dtype=np.float32)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] inputList=np.empty((max_size_inter,2), dtype=np.float32)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1 = clipPolygon[cp_size-1,:]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2=np.empty((2,), dtype=np.float32)

    outputList[:outputList_effective_size]=subjectPolygon
    for i in xrange(cp_size):

        cp2 = clipPolygon[i]
        inputList[:outputList_effective_size] = outputList[:outputList_effective_size]
        inputList_effective_size=outputList_effective_size
        outputList_effective_size=0
        s = inputList[inputList_effective_size-1]

        for j in xrange(inputList_effective_size):
            e = inputList[j]
            if inside(e, cp1, cp2):
                if not inside(s, cp1, cp2):                    
                    k+=1
                    outputList[k]=computeIntersection(cp1, cp2, e, s)

                k+=1
                outputList[k]=e


            elif inside(s, cp1, cp2):
                k+=1
                outputList[k]=computeIntersection(cp1, cp2, e, s)

            s = e

        if k<0:
            return np.empty((0,0),dtype=np.float32)





        outputList_effective_size=k+1

        cp1 = cp2
        k=-1

    return outputList[:outputList_effective_size]


cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] computeIntersection(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] e, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] s):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dc = cp1-cp2
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dp = s-e
    cdef np.float32_t n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
    cdef np.float32_t n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
    cdef np.float32_t n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
    return np.array([(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3], dtype=np.float32)


cdef bint inside(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] p, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2):
    return (cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])
```

Here is the benchmarks:

```
import numpy as np
from cython1 import clip_cython1
from cython2 import clip_cython2
import time


sp=np.array([[50, 150],[200,50],[350,150],[250,300],[200,250],[150,350],[100,250],[100,200]],dtype=np.float32)
cp=np.array([[100,100],[300,100],[300,300],[100,300]],dtype=np.float32)

t1=time.time()
for i in xrange(120000):
    a=clip_cython1(sp, cp)
t2=time.time()
print (t2-t1)

t1=time.time()
for i in xrange(120000):
    a=clip_cython2(sp, cp)
t2=time.time()
print (t2-t1)
```

39.45

44.12

The second one is even worse !

**EDIT 2** The best answer coming from @Peter Taylor from CodeReview use the fact that each time you compute inside_s it is redundant because s=e and you already calculated inside_e (and to factorize dc and n1 out of the functions but it does not help much).

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


def clip(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] subjectPolygon,np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] clipPolygon):


    outputList = list(subjectPolygon)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1 = clipPolygon[-1,:]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2 
    cdef bint inside_e, inside_s
    cdef np.float32_t n1
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dc 
    cdef int i



    for i in range(clipPolygon.shape[0]):

       cp2 = clipPolygon[i]
       #intermediate
       n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
       dc=cp1-cp2
       inputList = outputList
       outputList = []
       s = inputList[-1]

       inside_s=inside(s, cp1, dc)
       for index, subjectVertex in enumerate(inputList):

           e = subjectVertex
           inside_e=inside(e, cp1, dc)
           if inside_e:

               if not inside_s:
                   outputList.append(computeIntersection(dc, n1, e, s))
               outputList.append(e)

           elif inside_s:
               outputList.append(computeIntersection(dc, n1, e, s))

           s = e
           inside_s=inside_e

       if len(outputList)<1:
           return []
       cp1 = cp2

    return(outputList)


cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] computeIntersection(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dc, np.float32_t n1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] e, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] s):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dp = s-e
    cdef np.float32_t n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
    cdef np.float32_t n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
    return np.array([(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3], dtype=np.float32)


cdef bint inside(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] p, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dc):
    return (-dc[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (-dc[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])
```

Mixing the two versions (only numpy arrays and @Peter Taylor's tricks works slightly worse). No idea why ? Possibly because we have to allocate a long list of size sP.shape[0]*cp.shape[0] ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: @Prune if you follow this logic you would close at least a dozen of interesting and upvoted questions that can be found on stack.

Comment: @jean Cython can't improve lists much. Try to use numpy arrays instead - perhaps work out the maximum length `outputlist` can be (`2*len(inputlist)` I think?), allocate a numpy array, and trim the unused space when you're done.

Comment: @jean: I'm quite aware of other questions where an interesting language feature or program twist made a good question in this class.  I also note that I'm the only closure vote.  We're self-moderated, and not entirely consistent.

Comment: Note, too, that I didn't down-vote this: it's a good question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW I will look into that and add the benchmarks tomorrow.

Comment: @Prune I closed my question and moved it to codereview but another user told me that SO was more likely to get good answers so I reopened it but I understand your point.

Comment: I was also wondering if there was a way to integrate the additional functions computeIntersetions() and inside() more closely to speed things up ?

Comment: Sine I only want to use them inside this function.

Comment: I don't think something being on-topic for code review automatically makes it off-topic here, and you probably are more likely to get good answers here. I don't think `computeIntersections` and `inside` are your real problem right now, but you could make them `cdef` and add a return type.

Comment: @jean: LOL!  I withdraw my objections.

Comment: @DavidW I did not know about cdef function I will look into that and update it I received some good advices from codereview too. I will update both questions tomorrow I did not have time to look into it today.

Comment: @jean Try cython -a before compiling it will highlight your Python interactions that could be slowing things down (in an HTML file).  Also how many processors do you have?  OpenMP will usually give 3x speedup on 4 processors.  Another thing is to cdef inline those bottom 2 functions so the compiler can try to optimize them into your main function (without calling the actual functions)

Comment: @jean I already tried the above (less OpenMP) with no improvement.  I see you have a np.array return from computeIntersection.  This can be slow as you are reinvoking Python.  It is much faster to pass in the output matrix already defined prior to the function call to keep it on a C++ level.

Comment: @jean I just tried out your Python code you're trying to convert it is 3x faster than the Cython version!!!  Must have overcomplicated your Cython code here...

Comment: Thanks @Matt just came bak from vacations nice activities out here ! I am getting up to speed with all your answers and comments !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten a 15x speed up:

```
In [12]: timeit clippy.clip(clippy.sP, clippy.cP)
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop
In [13]: timeit clippy.clip1(clippy.sP, clippy.cP)
10000 loops, best of 3: 75.9 µs per loop
In [14]: timeit myclip.clip(clippy.sP, clippy.cP)
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.1 µs per loop
In [15]: timeit myclip.clip1(clippy.sP, clippy.cP)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.2 µs per loop
```

`clippy.clip` is your original function.

`clippy.clip1` is also Python, but replacing most of the list indexing with tuple unpacking.

```
def clip1(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):

   def inside(p0,p1):
      return(cp20-cp10)*(p1-cp11) > (cp21-cp11)*(p0-cp10)

   def computeIntersection():
      dc0, dc1 = cp10 - cp20, cp11 - cp21
      dp0, dp1 =  s0 - e0, s1 - e1
      n1 = cp10 * cp21 - cp11 * cp20
      n2 = s0 * e1 - s1 * e0
      n3 = 1.0 / (dc0 * dp1 - dc1 * dp0)
      return [(n1*dp0 - n2*dc0) * n3, (n1*dp1 - n2*dc1) * n3]

   outputList = subjectPolygon
   cp10, cp11 = clipPolygon[-1]

   for cp20, cp21 in clipPolygon:

      inputList = outputList
      #print(inputList)
      outputList = []
      s0,s1 = inputList[-1]
      s_in = inside(s0, s1)
      for e0, e1  in inputList:
         e_in = inside(e0, e1)
         if e_in:
            if not s_in:
               outputList.append(computeIntersection())
            outputList.append((e0, e1))
         elif s_in:
            outputList.append(computeIntersection())
         s0,s1,s_in = e0,e1,e_in
      if len(outputList)<1:
          return []
      cp10, cp11 = cp20, cp21
   return outputList
```

`myclip.clip` is the original `cythonized`; still working with lists, not arrays.

`myclip.clip1` is the 2nd `cythonized`:

```
cdef computeIntersection1(double cp10, double cp11, double cp20, double cp21,double s0, double s1,double e0, double e1):
  dc0, dc1 = cp10 - cp20, cp11 - cp21
  dp0, dp1 =  s0 - e0, s1 - e1
  n1 = cp10 * cp21 - cp11 * cp20
  n2 = s0 * e1 - s1 * e0
  n3 = 1.0 / (dc0 * dp1 - dc1 * dp0)
  return (n1*dp0 - n2*dc0) * n3, (n1*dp1 - n2*dc1) * n3

cdef cclip1(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):
   cdef double cp10, cp11, cp20, cp21
   cdef double s0, s1, e0, e1
   cdef double s_in, e_in

   outputList = subjectPolygon
   cp10, cp11 = clipPolygon[-1]

   for cp20, cp21 in clipPolygon:

      inputList = outputList
      #print(inputList)
      outputList = []
      s0,s1 = inputList[-1]
      #s_in = inside(s0, s1)
      s_in = (cp20-cp10)*(s1-cp11) - (cp21-cp11)*(s0-cp10)
      for e0, e1  in inputList:
         #e_in = inside(e0, e1)
         e_in = (cp20-cp10)*(e1-cp11) - (cp21-cp11)*(e0-cp10)
         if e_in>0:
            if s_in<=0:
               outputList.append(computeIntersection1(cp10,cp11,cp20,cp21,s0,s1,e0,e1))
            outputList.append((e0, e1))
         elif s_in>0:
            outputList.append(computeIntersection1(cp10,cp11,cp20,cp21,s0,s1,e0,e1))
         s0,s1,s_in = e0,e1,e_in
      if len(outputList)<1:
          return []
      cp10, cp11 = cp20, cp21
   return outputList

def clip1(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):
    return cclip1(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon)
```

The `-a` annotated `html` still shows quite a bit of yellow, but most of the calculations don't require Python.  In the `compute` function there's a Python check for 0 divisor, and Python call to build the return tuple.  And the tuple unpacking still calls Python.  So there's room for improvement.

In the Python code there's isn't any advantage to using `numpy`. The lists are small, and list element access is faster.  But in `cython` arrays may be  stepping stone to `typed memoryviews` and pure C code.

---

Other times.

Your 2nd edit:

```
In [24]: timeit edit2.clip(np.array(clippy.sP,np.float32), np.array(clippy.cP,np
    ...: .float32))
1000 loops, best of 3: 228 µs per loop
```

`@Matt's` boundingbox

```
In [25]: timeit clippy.polygon_clip(clippy.rp,clippy.cp,100,100,300,300)
1000 loops, best of 3: 208 µs per loop
```

### extension class

I cleaned up the code by defining an extension class

```
cdef class Point:
    cdef public double x, y
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

which lets me write things like:

```
  s = inputList[-1]
  s_in =  insideP(s, cp1, cp2)
```

The 'cover' function has to convert lists of tuples to lists of points and v.v.

```
sP = [Point(*x) for x in subjectPolygon]
```

There's a slight speed penalty to this.

Comment: @jean hpaulj's answer is a good one.  See my updated answer as well it has the same speed on a very poor AMD laptop and you can just download a whl and install w/pip

Comment: Thanks +1 you're Cython is a nice cleanup

Comment: Thank you very much @hpaulj I am benchmarking your solutions tomorrow looks dope !

Comment: This is amazing !!!! I got a 40X speed-up compared to my second edit ! I am actually quite puzzled at this how could you get such an immense speed-up, would you mind elaborating a bit more on how you came up with this ?

Comment: I tried to use line profiling in Cython but so far I could not get it working.

Comment: I focused on the '-a' html display of the 'pyx' file, trying to minimize the bright yellow lines.  Lines with '+'  also expand to show the c calls.

Answer (score 2):

After messing with your Cython code I figured it was way easier to find your library already implemented somewhere else, so check out the scikit-image version that is just several lines of Numpy code and the algo you're looking for from matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import path, transforms

def polygon_clip(rp, cp, r0, c0, r1, c1):
"""Clip a polygon to the given bounding box.

Parameters
----------
rp, cp : (N,) ndarray of double
    Row and column coordinates of the polygon.
(r0, c0), (r1, c1) : double
    Top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the bounding box.

Returns
-------
r_clipped, c_clipped : (M,) ndarray of double
    Coordinates of clipped polygon.

Notes
-----
This makes use of Sutherland-Hodgman clipping as implemented in
AGG 2.4 and exposed in Matplotlib.

"""
    poly = path.Path(np.vstack((rp, cp)).T, closed=True)
    clip_rect = transforms.Bbox([[r0, c0], [r1, c1]])
    poly_clipped = poly.clip_to_bbox(clip_rect).to_polygons()[0]

    # This should be fixed in matplotlib >1.5
    if np.all(poly_clipped[-1] == poly_clipped[-2]):
        poly_clipped = poly_clipped[:-1]

    return poly_clipped[:, 0], poly_clipped[:, 1]
```

If nothing else the above should be way simpler to convert to Cython.

[UPDATE]
And from the other Cython answer profiling try this package which is already implementing polygon clipping from C++ into Python called https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyclipper usage as such:

import pyclipper

subj = (
    ((180, 200), (260, 200), (260, 150), (180, 150)),
    ((215, 160), (230, 190), (200, 190))
)

clip = ((190, 210), (240, 210), (240, 130), (190, 130))

pc = pyclipper.Pyclipper()
pc.AddPath(clip, pyclipper.PT_CLIP, True)
pc.AddPaths(subj, pyclipper.PT_SUBJECT, True)

solution = pc.Execute(pyclipper.CT_INTERSECTION, pyclipper.PFT_EVENODD, pyclipper.PFT_EVENODD)

The above is about the same speed as the fast Cython code answer on my terrible AMD work PC BTW 9us.

Comment: In the case of a bounding box such as `cP` (100-300 in both dim), the makes the problem clearer.  But it isn't faster than the original Python.